# the reaction roles doesn't give me the role when I click it and I get no errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to figure out how to make the reaction roles to give me the roles i want but i dont get any errors and i don't get the roles added to myself at all when I execute the command and press the emojis, i also don't get any console logs and I've added console.log to the code. any help would be appreciated, i'm having a really hard time with this, please help me...

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { MessageReaction } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
  name: 'games',
  description: 'Select the games',
  async execute(message, args, Discord, bot) {
    if (message.member.roles.cache.has('552561546039918593')) {
      const channel = '905072473899409438';
      const gifsRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'GIF');
      const emojiRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'EMOJIS');

      const gifs = '<:hersheys:823607413843951646>';
      const emoji = '<:glokez:858101005512867892>';
      const gifsEmoij = '823607413843951646';
      const emojiEmoij = '858101005512867892';

      let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#e42643')
        .setTitle('<a:sparkles1:905070246610739240>  **Role Selection**')
        .setDescription(
          `Choose what roles you want to access!\n\n` +
            `${gifs}   **(**    GIF                       **)**\n` +
            `${emoji}   **(**    EMOJIS     **)**`,
        );

      let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
      messageEmbed.react(gifsEmoij);
      messageEmbed.react(emojiEmoij);

      client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
        console.log('0');
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
        console.log('1', reaction.message.channel.id === channel);
        if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {
          console.log('2', reaction.emoji.id === gifsEmoij.id);
          if (reaction.emoji.id === gifsEmoji.id) {
            console.log('3');
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(gifsRole);
          }
          if (reaction.emoji.id === emojiEmoji.id) {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(emojiRole);
          }
        } else {
          return;
        }
      });

      client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
        console.log('0');
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
        console.log('1', reaction.message.channel.id === channel);
        if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {
          console.log('2', reaction.emoji.id === gifsEmoij.id);
          if (reaction.emoji.id === gifsEmoji.id) {
            console.log('3');
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(gifsRole);
          }
          if (reaction.emoji.id === emojiEmoji.id) {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(emojiRole);
          }
        } else {
          return;
        }
      });
    }
  },
};
```